# How to find the dimensions of a dom-node before creating it?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

There is a `<ul>` list that I'm retrieving via XHR and inserting into another node (`<div>`). This list has a different number of elements every time (so the height of the resulting node varies).

I'd like to **animate** the `<div>` into which I'm inserting that list as it takes the new height. So, say the div was initially 100px, and the height of the XHR-retrieved list is going to be 150px, the `<div>` should smoothly expand to the new height of 150px.

To do this, I need the height of the rendered list (taking all the page styles into account) before it is actually rendered. **Question**: (a) how would you find the height, (b) do you see another way of doing this animation, and (c) is this at all possible?

Comment: Can't you render the DIV, check it's height and then animate it? Otherwise the calculations would be a bit extreme (IMHO).

Comment: @Jaroslav If I render it first in the div, the animation would have no value. The reason for the animation is to make the "jumpy" div expand in a bit more controlled, smoother, and as a result -- more user-friendly way.

Comment: that's why we have `visibility: hidden` and `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @Jaroslav good point. The combination of that and an extra wrapper is what did the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) as far as i know it isn't possible to accurately determin the height of a not yet rendered element
b) With jQuery's >[slideUp](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)> and [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) this is perfectly doable, are you using a framework?
c) yes, you might have to put a wrapper div around the  depending on the way you do it.

More:
By putting a wrapper <div> around your <ul> and setting th <div> to height:0 and overflow:hidden you can perfectly render the <ul> in it without showing it. Then you have plenty of time for javascript to get the dimensions of the <ul> and animate/resize the wrapping <div> to the <ul>'s height without ever showing your <ul>.

Comment: (b) yes -- dojo. Can you elaborate on how this would be doable please? (c) I'm not sure I follow. What should be wrapped, and why? Thanks.

Comment: Ow sorry, some content of my anwser was discarded due to html filtering, i've corrected and elaborated a little further.

Comment: Perfect - the wrapper did the trick. The only thing missing was "overflow: hidden". Add it for other folks and I'll mark this one done.